# How to automatically get all fields from the input source in Kettle?

Tags: mongodb, etl, kettle

I'm going to use Pentaho Kettle ETL tool for exporting data from our MongoDB collections into another output format for statistical analysis. **I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to make Kettle automatically export all fields that exist in particular collection's documents?**

I have to manually create a transformation process for non-trivial documents, but some fields are very simple and could be automatically fetched. I wonder if it is possible in Kettle, and how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

version 4.3 comes with MongoDB input step, and gets by default a collection, allowing to query using xpath expressions.

it's located under design tab, and click on "Big Data" folder.